# Saving virtual machine into an image using azure python sdk

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-sdk-python

I have been working with Microsoft Azure to build virtual machines using the Azure SDK for Python, and now  I want to create a managed image from an existing virtual machine.

I saw that there is a way to do it in power shell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource)

But after a long research i didn't find how to do it in python sdk.
My goal is to be able to save a virtual machine into an image and load it 
afterwards (I'm using the ARM and not the ASM).

Answer (score 1):

After a long time trying to figure this out I was finally able to capture an image from a vm.
firstly, the vm needs to be dealocated and generalized:

```
# Deallocate
async_vm_deallocate = self.compute_client.virtual_machines.deallocate(resource_group.name, names.vm)
async_vm_deallocate.wait()

# Generalize (possible because deallocated)
self.compute_client.virtual_machines.generalize(resource_group.name, names.vm)
```

I found that there are 2 options to creating the image:

1. `compute_client.virtual_machines.capture(resource_group_name=resource_group.name, vm_name=vm.name, parameters=parameters)`

this way requires creating a **ComputeManagmentClient** and the following import:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute.v2015_06_15.models import VirtualMachineCaptureParameters
```

the parameters have to be object type: ~azure.mgmt.compute.v2015_06_15.models.VirtualMachineCaptureParameters.

The object **VirtualMachineCaptureParameters** has 3 required params:
vhd_name_prefix (str), destination container name (str), overwrite vhds (bool)

what these are, I have no idea and there is no explanation as to what they are. so I didnt use this way

2. (the way I choose to use) `compute_client.images.create_or_update(resource_group_name=resource_group, image_name=unique_name, parameters=params)`

this way requires creating a **ComputeManagmentClient** and the following import:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.models import Image, SubResource
```

and it is pretty straight forward

```
sub_resource = SubResource(id=vm.id)
params = Image(location=LOCATION, source_virtual_machine=sub_resource)
i = compute_client.images.create_or_update(resource_group_name=resource_group, image_name=image_name, parameters=params)
i.wait()
```

creating the **SubResource()** and the **Image()** objects is mandatory as that is the object type expected

Comment: Hey there, I follow the same steps and was able to save the VM into an image. But when I try to create new VM's using the image it fails with the below error.
```msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: OSProvisioningClientError
Message: OS Provisioning for VM 'xx' did not finish in the allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either use the VHD as is with CreateOption=Attach or prepare it properly for use as an image```

Answer (score 0):

Create a compute client:

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage

Deallocate and generalize:

```
    # Deallocate
    async_vm_deallocate = self.compute_client.virtual_machines.deallocate(resource_group.name, names.vm)
    async_vm_deallocate.wait()

    # Generalize (possible because deallocated)
    self.compute_client.virtual_machines.generalize(resource_group.name, names.vm)
```

Create an image, there an operation group `compute_client.images`. I have no exact example like yours, but see this one to create an image from a blob (can be adapted to your scenario):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-samples-managed-disks#create-an-image-from-blob-storage

Comment: Hi Laurent, thanks for your help.

At this point I have created several virtual machines under different resource groups. The question now is where do I get the "blob_uri" from?

As quoted in [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-samples-managed-disks?view=azure-python#virtual-machine-with-managed-disks), I need not worry about storage accounts anymore, therefore how will I be able to obtain the blob or .vhd file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to manage yourself blob and vhd, you can't use managed disk. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388855/how-to-get-the-vhd-of-an-azure-managed-disk